# Importing module: works with ipython but it doesn't if I'm not using ipython

Tags: python, import, ipython, importerror

I have a directory which can be simplified to

```
proyect/
|-- src/
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- frontend/
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- file_select.py
|   |-- config/
|       |-- __init__.py
|       |-- variables.py
```

In `file_select.py` I want to import `variables.py` as a module. To this end, I use `from src.config import variables as var`. If I then run ipython on the terminal and then run `file_select.py`, it works wonders (in the sense that the module runs with no issues). The problem is that, if I don't us ipython on the terminal, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\spinc\Desktop\proyect\src\frontend\file_select.py", line 3, in <module>
    from src.config import variables as var
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

`file_select.py` uses the libraries `tkinter` and `tkinterdnd2` while `variables.py` uses no libraries at all.

I tried using `from ..config import variables` but this doesn't work by running it directly on the terminal nor does it work in ipython. I'm not sure what could the issue be and why would it work by running it in ipython but not by running it directly on the terminal.

I'm expecting for the module to work wheter I'm on ipython or not.

What changes can I make so that the import is successful regardless of whether I'm using ipython or not?

### Apendix:

The content of each file:

`file_select.py`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinterdnd2 import *
from src.config import variables as var

background = var.background
[...]
```

`variables.py`

```
background = "#000739"
title = "Title"
```

Comment: What is the current directory when you run with ipython, and what is the current directory when you run the code the other way?

Comment: @JohnGordon, by typing %pwd in ipython I get:
'C:\\Users\\spinc\\Desktop\\proyect'.
The terminal for when I run it in python reads:
C:\Users\spinc\Desktop\proyect>
when it's turned on.

Comment: The issue get's solved if I import path from pathlib and sys and then add 
sys.path.append(str(Path(__file__).resolve().parents[2])) 
to the beginning of file_select.py. This is the approach I'll take for now but I'd still like to know why it only worked on ipython and if this solution is recommended.